# How to properly execute an executable supplied by a package that I wrote (or cloned), without also creating a package that uses it?

Tags: node.js, node-modules, pnpm

I created a package named `env-subset` that supplies an executable via the `bin` key in `package.json`:

```
  "bin": {
    "env-subset": "./index.js"
  },
```

Is there an official blessed way to make this executable actually materialize somewhere so that I can execute it, without doing any of the following:

- explicitly creating another package that pulls my package as a dependency
- installing my package globally, i.e. implicitly pulling it as a dependency of the implicit global package
- writing a wrapper script that executes `node path/to/my/env-subset/index.js` and low key hopes it won't fail in a thousand places?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install your package as a dependency of itself:

```
pnpm add -D env-subset@link:
```

Now you can run:

```
pnpm env-subset
```

Or:

```
./node_modules/.bin/env-subset
```

Comment: It does work, but the trick is IMO rather hard to discover. First, one must even _think_ of "installing a package as a dependency of itself", and that is not super thinkable. Then one must know about the more esoteric things that can go in the `<pkg>` slot in `pnpm add <pkg>`, but arent mentioned on https://pnpm.io/cli/add.